# Android App Development Slider Menu/Pop Up ----- Need assistance

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, slider

I'm trying to create a slider menu that slides in from the right and allows me to select an item from a list of buttons. Upon selecting that item, that slider disappears and the new slider with all the information in that section displays. Example. If the side menu buttons display food and the next drink. If I select food, it will display a Food Menu with various items. If I select Pizza it will have that menu disappear and slide out a new menu displaying everything about pizza. Sorry, new to Android app development. This is what I have so far... I need all the help possible. And I'm working only with Kotlin right now.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".menu">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/food"
        android:layout_width="34dp"
        android:layout_height="257dp"
        android:text="Food"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/drinks"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="2dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/drinks"
        android:layout_width="34dp"
        android:layout_height="257dp"
        android:text="Drinks"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/food"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="2dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I create programmatical keyboard in my masters. It look, like (letters on picture are not English, but i think, you understand this):
[image] May, you find it helpful.

Keyboard is the horizontal recyclerView. Look at this. (you can simplify it)
**Adapter**

```
class KeyboardAdapter(context: Context, private var listener: PressKeyboardButton) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemKeyboardViewHolder>() {
    private var keyboard: ArrayList<KeyBtn> = ArrayList()
    private var inflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)

    init {
        initKeyboard()
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemKeyboardViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindTo(keyboard[position])
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ItemKeyboardViewHolder {
        return ItemKeyboardViewHolder.create(inflater, viewGroup, listener)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return keyboard.size
    }

    fun initKeyboard(){
        keyboard.clear()
        keyboard.add(KeyBtn("dote", ".", KeyBtn.ADD))
        keyboard.add(KeyBtn("0", "0", KeyBtn.ADD))
        keyboard.add(KeyBtn("1", "1", KeyBtn.ADD))
        keyboard.add(KeyBtn("backspace", "backspace", KeyBtn.BACKSPACE))
        keyboard.add(KeyBtn("delete", "delete", KeyBtn.DELETE))

        this.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun initKeyboard(numbers: ArrayList<CustomNumber>) {
        initKeyboard()

        // additional buttons
        for (number in numbers)      // Conversation format to Summation format (0.000000.000 -> 00.000000.000)
            keyboard.add(KeyBtn(number.comment, number.numberString, KeyBtn.REINIT))

        this.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }


    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    fun updateTextEdit(keyBtn: KeyBtn, numberField: EditText?, comment: TextView?, context: Context) {
        if(numberField != null) {
            val start = Math.max(numberField.selectionStart, 0)
            val end = Math.max(numberField.selectionEnd, 0)
            val length = numberField.text.toString().length

            when (keyBtn.typeButton) {
                KeyBtn.REINIT -> {
                    numberField.setText(keyBtn.data)
                    if (comment != null)
                        comment.text = "// ${keyBtn.text}"
                }
                KeyBtn.ADD -> {
                    numberField.text.replace(Math.min(start, end), Math.max(start, end),
                            keyBtn.data, 0, keyBtn.data.length)
                }
                KeyBtn.BACKSPACE -> {
                    numberField.text.replace(Math.max(0, start - 1), end, "", 0, 0)
                }
                KeyBtn.DELETE -> {
                    numberField.text.replace(start, Math.min(length, end + 1), "", 0, 0)
                }
            }

            val vibrator = context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 26)
                oldVibrate(vibrator)
            else
                newVibrate(vibrator)
        }
    }

    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    private fun oldVibrate(vibrator: Vibrator){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 26)
            vibrator.vibrate(27)
    }

    private fun newVibrate(vibrator: Vibrator){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
            val effect = VibrationEffect.createOneShot(27, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE)
            vibrator.vibrate(effect)
        }
    }
}


interface PressKeyboardButton {
    fun simpleClick(keyBtn: KeyBtn, context: Context)
}
```

And so it **ViewHolder**:

```
class ItemKeyboardViewHolder private constructor(private val view: View,
                                                 private val listener: PressKeyboardButton) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view), View.OnTouchListener {
    val itemKeyboard = view.itemKeyboard!!

    companion object {
        fun create(inflater: LayoutInflater,
                   parent: ViewGroup,
                   listener: PressKeyboardButton
        ): ItemKeyboardViewHolder {
            return ItemKeyboardViewHolder(
                    inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_keyboard, parent, false),
                    listener)
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    fun bindTo(keyBtn: KeyBtn) {
        itemKeyboard.text = keyBtn.text
        view.setOnClickListener { listener.simpleClick(keyBtn, view.context) }
        view.setOnTouchListener(this)
    }

    override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        when (event?.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> itemKeyboard.isSelected = true
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL -> itemKeyboard.isSelected = false
        }

        return false
    }
}
```

And so layouts:

**ViewHolder**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/itemLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemKeyboard"
        style="@style/main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="A" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Recycler View**

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/keyboard"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/sign_in_gradient"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomSpacer"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

And the finishing init adapters:

```
// a custom simple keyboard
keyboardAdapter = KeyboardAdapter(this, object : PressKeyboardButton {
    override fun simpleClick(keyBtn: KeyBtn, context: Context) {
        val numberField: EditText? = currentFragment.recyclerViewAdapter?.getFocusedEditText()
        val commentField: TextView? = currentFragment.recyclerViewAdapter?.getFocusedCommentField()
        keyboardAdapter.updateTextEdit(keyBtn, numberField, commentField, context)
    }
})
val horizontalLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
keyboard.layoutManager = horizontalLayoutManager
keyboard.adapter = keyboardAdapter
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is still way out there for me. Can you break it down and which compenents go where? Im still learning app development.

Comment: sorry, i read question again, and uderstand, that my answer is not correct answer. May you should to use https://android-arsenal.com/tag/138?sort=created ? This site has a lot of good small library. Check it)